# java compilation error in eclipse helios

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation

I have executable jar file which is running perfectly when i am double clicking on it. but when i extracted the source code from jar file using jdk gui and trying to execute it in eclipse helios it is displaying the following errors

1. The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for ControlPoint. Fix the build path then try building this project
2. The type ControlPoint cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

I tried refreshing the source folder, changing the output folder of eclipse, but nothing worked for me.

Can anyone please help.

Comment: does this jar have any other dependencies (other required jar which you have in classpath when running)? you could check the manifest of the jar to find out.

Comment: When I double clicked the jar file, it run as an application, after extracting the source it is showing these errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify the right JRE in your buildpath. Also, you need to check if all the required libraries are added to the buildpath.

Comment: how to check what libraries are required?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to build and run until classpath is fixed. Check whether a library containing ControlPoint class is in class path, if not, then add it there.

You can find the library this way
http://www.findjar.com/index.x;jsessionid=EBF627F4D0BAEC200B8DF6DE50C3C47B?query=ControlPoint

If the ControlPoint class is in the sources that you extracted then make sure that this source folder is in the sources paths, if not add it there in project properties -> java build path -> source

Comment: Should I add all jar files which is displaying in the search result?

Comment: No, just one of them which fits, i.e. contains other needed classes and their correct versions